# reverse() raises NoReverseMatch when two apps use the same namespace

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use `reverse()` in a unit test, but it is not able to resolve the url.

`tests.py`:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

class MyTest(APITestCase):
    def test_cust_lookup(self):
        url = reverse('v1:customer')
        # Other code
```

The test case fails in the first line of the test with the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'customer' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}'  not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Does "0 patterns tried" means the test is not even able to find the root `urls.py`?  Or is there something else that I misconfigured?

`proj/settings.py`:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'proj.urls'
```

`proj/myapp/urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'cust/$', views.CustomerView.as_view(), name='customer')
]
```

`proj/urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^api1/v1/', include('myapp1.urls', namespace='v1')),
    url(r'^api2/v1/', include('myapp2.urls', namespace='v1'))
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't have different apps under same url namespace, Django isn't able to deal with it and doesn't tell you that that's the issue.  Change the namespaces to be unique for each app.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^api1/v1/', include('myapp1.urls', namespace='app1-v1')),
    url(r'^api2/v1/', include('myapp2.urls', namespace='app2-v1'))
]
```

Reverse the url with `reverse('app1-v1:customer')`.

Answer (score 0):

Your setting should be

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'
```

not

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'ommodels.urls'
```

Comment: I tried that too.. It threw - `Import Error: No module named urls`

Comment: Note: I have projects root `urls.py`, `settings.py`, and other stuffs in nested `proj` directory, and not parallel to my `myapp` directory

Comment: try: `ROOT_URLCONF = 'proj.urls'`

Comment: then try for 'proj.urls' as ROOT_URLCONF